# Raid Reconfiguration

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware-raid

We have a Hp DL 380 G6 server. we added extra hard drives and configured them using raid 5. we restarted the server and now we cannot see the drives with the os and the server will not load.
Is there a way to rebuild the raid?

Comment: can you clarify please.  How were the drives setup before this configuration and how are the drives setup now? What did you do exactly to reconfigure?

Answer (score 0):

You've not taken the array over the 2TB 'limit' have you?

Answer (score 0):

If you boot off of the SmartStart CD and open the ACU, can you see the original array / logical drives?  If the original disks haven't been overwritten, but the logical drives have disappeared, you should be able to re-create them, as long as you know their original size (exact to the MB).  The data will then "re-appear".

The number of logical drives also gets displayed during POST.